# Angularjs - view and edit an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i would like to have a list with entries of objects. If i click on an entry in that list i want to see the details of the object and an edit button on an area at the right side of the list. If i click that button the details disappers and a form to edit the object should appear.

**html**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr 
        ng-repeat="object in objects" 
        ng-click="select(object.id)"
    >
        <td>{{object.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button ng-click="edit(selectedObject.id)">Edit</button>

<div class="view">
    Name: {{selectedObject.name}}
</div>

<form>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input ng-model="object.name">
</form>
```

**controller.js**

```
myModule.controller('MyController', function($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.objects = MyService.getObjects();

    $scope.select = function(id) {
        $scope.selectedObject = angular.copy(MyService.getObject(id));  
    };

    $scope.edit = function(id) {
        ...
    };
});
```

In the edit function i could use the selectedObject, but maybe in future i also want to edit the object directly without selecting it before. So first i could do the same like in the select function but then i would call the service twice to receive the same object...

Also i don't know really how to handle the toggle between view- and editmode.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: 1. How can i toggle between view- and editmode, that only the active one is visible? 2. How should i handle it to receive the object i want to view or edit just once

Answer (score 0):

You should give the detail view and the edit form their own Controller, that way they're ready to be seperated.

Also a strong recommendation is using https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router Nested-Views and  Multiple/Named Views to manage your controllers.

You can then make the list view the parent and add the other 2 as child views with their own url like `/item/:id/view` and `/item/:id/edit`, see `$stateParams` for getting the values from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about your question but you could show/hide the input

```
$scope.edit = function () {
        $scope.editmode = true
};
```

and

```
<div class="view" ng-show="!editMode">    
    Name: {{selectedObject.name}}
</div>
```

with

```
ng-show="editmode"
```

on the input

or you could use

`ng-readonly="!editmode"` on the input (then you won't need another div to display the name)

If your planning to display obejcts has a table, please consider ngGrid which allows editing inside the grid itself